# Node js project firefox issue

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am running a project of nodejs in amazon linux ami. The project is showing fine in chrome and safari. But in "Mozilla firefox" the project is broken.What I found css and javascript file can not be connected for "https" issue;It's showing in console "Content Security Policy: Upgrading insecure request ‘http://52.43.225.170:8000/tacticalsales/assets/css/style.css’ to use ‘https’".same for "js".

I hardcoded the js and css link file with "http" But it didn't work.

I am confused is it a browser issue,project configuration issue or server issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's a server configuration problem. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/upgrade-insecure-requests. Have you tried reading about the problem on the mozilla documentation?

Comment: But why it's working with chrome and safari?

Comment: @ShawonMorshed because Chrome and Safari are not Firefox. Different browsers, different default security settings.